# /articles leaks top secret AudioBubble collective articles

Tags: bug, status-completed, privacy, collectives, articles

https://stackoverflow.com/articles has some articles from the AudioBubble™ Collective™ (which is used for testing Collectives™ in production), which is not public. These articles should not be listed there, since they 404 when visited (and presumably include top-secret AudioBubble™-internal information).

[image: A list of two Collectives articles, "Testing Suggestions for Audio Bubble" and "Test Article for AudioBubble"]

(Also, is there a space in AudioBubble or not? IMO, it works way better without the space.)

Comment: 1) From a nihilist view on Collectives, does it really matter anymore if they're not exactly hidden? There were four rolled out initially, with I think two or three hidden. 2) Nothing on the internet is top secret, so if it's here, some level of risk of it leaking is inherently accepted.

Comment: I tried AudioBubble once. It is a scam.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

/articles was not ready to be released in StackOverflow. I have hid it for now until we can fix it completely.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to this information being (partially) visible on /article, if you visit the profile of any of the authors, the **entire article** is visible there under the [all actions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14649843/carog?tab=activity) tab along with any comments that the user has posted to the article:

[image]

This will likely need to be fixed separately but I'm posting it here rather than in a new question because it's very closely related to the current bug report.

Comment: Noted as well, thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this. [It's fixed now.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413619/17016916)

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the bug report. This has been fixed; non-public article activity should now be hidden from user profiles.