# Why doesn't the /articles page show that an article has a negative score?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, downvotes, collectives, articles

Compare the posts in this screenshot, from the [All articles](https://stackoverflow.com/articles) tab:

[image]

The one on the bottom ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel/articles/69812928/)) has a positive score of +3, and it is shown as such on the page.  The one on top, however ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel/articles/69815104/)) has a score of -14, and the score is not shown.  This is consistent throughout all the articles on that page.  Why?  Aside from being inconsistent from the normal vote-showing on Stack Overflow Main (and everywhere else on the network), why are we hiding the negative count?

Comment: I think we all know the answer... To maintain the appearance that everything is a-ok whereas it is far from it in reality. I sincerely hope this to be an oversight/bug, but I have a gut feeling this is intentional. Hope to be proven wrong

Comment: @OlegValter If that's by design, I'm not satisfied with it and that's why I asked.  If it's a bug, let's get it fixed - although it's not urgent if it *is* a bug IMHO.

Comment: Yeah, and I fully support this question - I am outspoken in being very annoyed by hiding vote breakdowns until a user reaches 1000 rep which makes controversial posts appear positively received for the majority of the audience. And this instance is *way* worse as I suspect it deliberately hides negative scores so that the page appears squeaky clean. I sincerely hope it is an oversight, though, and will be relieved if it is

Comment: IMO, it's worse than just hiding negative scores. It substitutes a different metric, views, which makes the page confusing. When first glancing at the page, those numbers are *assumed* to be score, because that's what's shown everywhere else on SE. When interpreted as score, that's *very* misleading. Mixing in a different metric in such a prominent place makes it effectively impossible for users to make informed choices as to what articles they will click-through to read.

Comment: @Makyen every single time I open the /article page it takes me a full minute to understand what is going on between views and votes. I'm like "woah one article with 1k votes, that must be interesting!" but then I realize it's views. It's so confusing... current design makes little-to-no sense IMO.

Comment: Voting on articles doesn't serve the same purpose as voting in Q&A. Articles don't get closed, they don't get roomba'd, they aren't sorted by score, negatively scored aren't hidden, so... What... purpose does voting serve for articles? I'm not necessarily saying I want voting removed, but, if none of the quality metrics voting is meant to serve are being used...

Comment: Side note: I find it odd that the 2 "AudioBubble" links are broken. I'm assuming they are deleted for anyone under 10k? But if they are deleted, then why do they still display? I'm not going to write a question about it, but there seems to be a lot of oddities with that list of articles.

Comment: @computercarguy See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412862/articles-leaks-top-secret-audiobubble-collective-articles). They're not supposed to be in the list and will be removed.

Comment: eh, i guess technically the sorting does still come into play in on-site search results, if sorted by votes rather than relevance.

Comment: Like @BrianThompson mentioned, this issue is related to the one posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412862/articles-leaks-top-secret-audiobubble-collective-articles). This page was not designed for Public SO (it's leftover from Teams). Our intention was not to hide downvotes on articles in this list view. We plan to remove this page entirely for now. If we decide to bring it back to Public SO, the design will be adapted.

Comment: @Carog well, that is somewhat of a relief, I am glad to be proven more paranoid than *less* :) On the note of removing the page, though - wouldn't it be better to just fix it up to be viable for public access rather than removing it? It looks hella convenient, and if articles are going to stay (and it seems they are), it makes sense for the community to have access to tooling like this. It might be easier to create a new one in terms of effort, but it would be a shame to lose it *completely*. Per-collective article pages are good and all, but they, well, are limited to a single collective.

Comment: The latest edit to your title is confusing. The articles page *does* show articles which are negatively scored, it just doesn't show the negative score, which is what the original title said.

Comment: @cigien Sorry, I wanted it to be more plural there, but that sounds like it's not showing the post at all.

Comment: @OlegValter There are definitely some positive aspects of having that page I agree, but there's more work needed to make it happen (design, research, performance, security...) and it's not something we'd planned. We need more time to consider all use cases. So for now, that page will be hidden, as it should have been in the first place.

Comment: The link in question 404s for me. I had no idea that any such site feature was ever active, or even planned. I assume it's being reworked or rethought?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel See Carog's comments above - they plan to remove it entirely for the present.

Comment: @Carog yeah, that sounds reasonable - as I mentioned, I suspect that the dev cost involved might not be worth it. Please do consider adding it back in some new form - it provides a nice overview of articles for all collectives at once

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! This issue is related to the one posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412862/articles-leaks-top-secret-audiobubble-collective-articles).

This page was not designed for Public SO (it's a leftover from Teams). Our intention was not to hide downvotes on articles on this page (our intention was not for this page to exist at all). We agree that this page (when designed and set up correctly for the Public SO) might have value to the community, however, this has several implications (design, research, performance, security) and therefore we've decided to remove the page for now.

If we decide to bring it back to Public SO, the design will be adapted.