# Why does this user's account have rep points seemingly out of nowhere?

Tags: bug, reputation, collectives, reputation-history

I was checking the "All actions" tab on the [profile of a staff member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14649843/carog) with regards to another bug report when I noticed that they have no posts or approved edits but they have 31 reputation points. In an attempt to find out where this discrepancy comes from, I visited their [Reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14649843/carog?tab=reputation) and found that they have received 10 points on three separate days but there are no visible events for any of them:

[image]

Those also cannot be upvotes on deleted answers because they would have to have had a score of 3+ *and* they would still be visible in the public profile, AFAIK.

So, where does this rep come from?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They have 3 upvotes in a post in a collective you don't have access to (note they created a post in the Audio Bubble collective): https://stackoverflow.com/users/14649843/carog?tab=activity&sort=all

Comment: The collective article you're referring to was created last month (that's actually the [bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412892/8967612) that I referred to above). Those rep changes are way older.

Comment: The timing looks a bit suspect though, otherwise this could be plausible

Comment: What makes it suspect? Why would it not be used in on going testing.

Comment: This is the direct link https://stackoverflow.com/articles/66782918/the-science-of-pickles They got 3 upvotes on this article

Comment: This is probably what happened. I crafted a network request to upvote the hidden article (the backend doesn't stop you from upvoting articles you can't see), and Carog's reputation went up by 10.

Comment: @smitop sneak level: 100. Impressive.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413619/14649843 It seems that while the test article was leaked, somebody upvoted it (we only know that it's not an employee so could be any SO user). If I could give the rep back I would but if somebody chooses to upvote my fake test articles, I can't stop them.

Comment: @Carog I assume you're not talking about Smitop [who openly admitted to it a couple comments above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412923/why-does-this-users-account-have-rep-points-seemingly-out-of-nowhere/412924?noredirect=1#comment878340_412924)? :p

Comment: "I crafted a network request to upvote the hidden article (the backend doesn't stop you from upvoting articles you can't see), and Carog's reputation went up by 10".   Y'all keeping us honest, I see :)  Putting this on the (short) list to fix.

Comment: @Nick I mean... I can neither confirm nor deny such a claim, I didn't want to presume on comments alone. And that only accounts for 1 upvote (unless Simtop did it a few times) :)

Answer (score 7):

The reputation for this staff member does indeed come from upvotes on articles that belong to a Collective meant for testing. We've taken action to hide these testing posts from user's profiles but some items remain off (article count and reputation). Fixing these is a larger effort than we'd like at this time.

Comment: So the follow up question should be how did you end up with 2 rep on SO Meta but only 1 rep on SO main. 2 rep is an awfully difficult achievement especially when it's only on Meta.