# Reputation history links to not-existing or inaccessible Collective article

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, collectives, 404-not-found

This *might* be caused by the recently launched [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/295232) but I don't think so. I encountered this following the Meta Stack Exchange question [When are hidden comunities displayed on the View All page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372789/295232)

[The profile page of a staff member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14649843/carog?tab=topactivity) shows a +20 reputation for a Collective article:

[image]

but when I visit the link `https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/audiobubble/articles/69624295/testing-suggestions-for-audio-bubble` it returns a 404.

I have no problem with users having more reputation than I can account for with public information, but it would be better if that entry is completely hidden from the profile.

Comment: Related [Why does this user's account have rep points seemingly out of nowhere?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412923/15497888)

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412892. This new bug could be a side effect of [the recent fix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/412892/timeline#comment_883627) of the linked one.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, we agree with @Glorfindel's note and will be hiding the post entry entirely from the profile. On the short list to fix.

Comment: @41686d6564 I missed a few (obvious) areas on my last fix but they should be addressed  now. Let us know if you see anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this! These articles we used for testing should now be hidden on user profiles.

However, there are some lingering effects visible on one SO employee's profile (the article count is off and reputation) which will remain. Fixing these is a larger effort than we'd like and we believe that time is better spent elsewhere.