# Test articles are showing up in search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, collectives, articles

When [searching using is:article](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aarticle), test articles are appearing.

[image: Screenshot showing test articles appearing in search]

This is somewhat similar to [a past occurrence regarding the /articles page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412862/articles-leaks-top-secret-audiobubble-collective-articles). However, I figured it deserved its own post, given this is a different way of pulling in the test articles.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for reporting this! The search index logic has been updated to exclude articles related to private Collectives (which we use for internal testing/verification and for pre-staging new Collectives before the go live).